# Delphi, When a datamodule loads I like to prevent the TFDConnector from connecting if I mistakenly have the activate set true

Tags: delphi, database-connection, datamodule

It often happens, to me, that after testing and making a build while I forget to check the activate property first. Then when I install the program on a different system an exception occurs due to failed connection. It's really annoying.

I've searched for a solution for a long time but it looks like it is impossible without making a new connection component inherited from TFDConnection. I don't want to do that and maybe someone here knows a simple way to get around this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the property `ConnectedStoredUsage` in `TFDConnection`.
That controls how to use the `Connected` property value saved to the DFM.

So for your need, you can uncheck `auRunTime`.

For more info on [ConnectedStoredUsage](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.ConnectedStoredUsage), see the DocWiki.

Comment: Perfect! I don't understand how I could miss this property.